# MS Access VBA- Filter subform from another subform (within a navigation from of a main form)

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I have an unbounded Form Called [frmTestsMain] which includes 3 subforms:

1. [frmTestsList]
2. [frmTMGroupList]
3. [frmTSGroupList]

---

- [frmTMGroup] has a filed "TMGroup",
- [frmTSGroup] has a filed called "TSGroup"  and another lookup filed
  "TMGroup" linked to [frmTMGroup].TMGroup.
- [frmTestsList] has lookup filed "TSGroup" linked to [frmTSGroup].TSGroup.

---

What I want is:

1. When I click  [frmTMGroup].TMGroup, the other subform [frmTSGroup] to be filtered to get only TMGroup clicked.
2. When I click [frmTSGroup].TSGroup, the other subform [frmTestsList] to be filtered to get only TSGroup clicked.

I wrote the code like below and worked with no problems If I open the [frmTestsMain] directly.

```
Private Sub TestMGroup_Click()
Forms![frmTestsMain]![frmTSGroupList].Form.Filter = "TestMGroup =" & Me.ID

Forms![frmTestsMain]![frmTSGroupList].Form.FilterOn = True 
 End Sub
```

and

```
 Private Sub TestSGroup_Click()
 Forms![frmTestsMain]![frmTestsList].Form.Filter = "TestSGroup =" & Me.ID
 Forms![frmTestsMain]![frmTestsList].Form.FilterOn = True
 End Sub
```

But when I included the [frmTestsMain] from in A navigation form with a min from , i get an error.

I tried to modify the code like the following but I get the same problem

```
Private Sub TestMGroup_Click()
Forms![frmMain]![NaviTests]![frmTestsMain]![frmTSGroupList].Form.Filter = "TestMGroup =" & Me.ID

Forms![frmMain]![NaviTests]![frmTestsMain]![frmTSGroupList].Form.FilterOn = True 
 End Sub
```

Could you help me please. 
Thanks

Comment: i read this post but could not understand the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041901/access-vba-subform-not-filtering-other-subform-when-embbedded-in-navigation-form

Comment: Is `TestMGroup` a number or a string? If it's a string you have to surround `Me.ID` with quotes `.Filter = "TestMGroup = '" & Me.ID & "'"`

Comment: I modified the code to be : Forms![frmMain]![NaviTests]![frmTestsMain]![frmTSGroupList].Form.Filter = "TestMGroup =" & Me.ID & "'"   OR as  Forms![frmTestsMain]![frmTSGroupList].Form.Filter = "TestMGroup =" & Me.ID & "'"   but i still get an errorbut i still get an error

Comment: The error details: run-time error '438' : Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions, and thanks for all the people here and there who helped me to figure it out

```
Private Sub TestMGroup_Click()
Forms![frmMain]![NavigationSubform].Form![frmTSGroupList].Form.Filter = "TestMGroup =" & Me.ID
Forms![frmMain]![NavigationSubform].Form![frmTSGroupList].Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Thanks